# Using VBA excel to decrypt files PGP

Tags: vba, excel, encryption, pgp

I use a program that pulls encrypted files down each day from an FTP.  I would like to create a macro in an excel document that will decrypt the file using PGP.

Is this possible?  I already know how to search the file for each specific file.

I've researched around and have not found anything useful as of yet.  Any point in the right direction would be great.  Even if the answer is this cannot be done.

Thank you,
Michael

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easiest way to decrypt PGP-encrypted files from VBA (MS Access)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139046/easiest-way-to-decrypt-pgp-encrypted-files-from-vba-ms-access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a COM or ActiveX component for PGP which decrypts a PGP message. There appear to be a few about, for example [this](http://www.winsite.com/pgp/pgp+activex+component/freeware/) one (that's not a recommendation, BTW!)

Install it on your PC, and then in Excel VB windows add a project reference to it via the Tools > References menu: find the PGP component in the list and select it. You can then use the objects it exposes in VBA code - you'll have to look at any documentation it has for the COM objects it exposes and how to use them.

Cheers -